# failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "signal" referenced by "libSDL2.so"

Tags: android, sdl, sdl-2

building an Android application using the SDL, I am loading this in the java file using
System.loadLibrary("SDL2");but when I try to run the application on an android tablet, it gives the following error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol “signal” referenced by “libSDL2.so”…"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your ndk platform version matches your phone's architecture.  I had to experiment with a few different ndk versions to figure it out myself.  If that fails, perhaps you are experiencing SFO's problem in the post below where he had to revert to r9 from r10.

Comment: Can you include the information from the post you're referring to? Either you forgot a link or the other post disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Changing back to r9 didn't work for me. 
I had to revert from r10e do r10b.
Don't know why, but I tried r11c, r9d, r9, r10e, but r10b was the only that I was able to get rid of this problem.

Comment: I had the same issue when trying to build a Kivy app for an LG G2, and using specifically version r10b fixed my issues.