# Dev kermit binary is not working in android board

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

I tried to compile devkermit c source using ndk .
I am getting the following error while running the binary in board
**CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: ****cannot locate symbol "signal" referenced by "./devkermit"...**

Please Help me.

Comment: if you're using ndk10, try to revert to ndk9 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641583/failed-dlopen-failed-cannot-locate-symbol-signal-referenced-by-libsdl2-so?answertab=active#tab-top